# MongoDB find multiple array items and get the latest items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following documents

```
{
  name: "John",
  ipaddr: ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3']
  update: 168450500
}

{
  name: "Eric",
  ipaddr: ['1.1.1.1','4.4.4.4']
  update: 168450400
}

{
  name: "Tom",
  ipaddr: ['3.3.3.3']
  update: 168450300
}
```

And I want to find ip: ['1.1.1.1','4.4.4.4']. If there's a duplicated item, the latest update timestamp will be used

The expected result should be:

```
1.1.1.1 => John
4.4.4.4 => Eric
```

My current solution is to use `$in: ['1.1.1.1','4.4.4.4']` and post-processing it on the application level. I would like to know if I can perform this task just with Mongodb Query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      ipaddr: { $in: [ "1.1.1.1", "4.4.4.4" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      ipaddr: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$ipaddr",
          cond: { $in: [ "$$this", [ "1.1.1.1", "4.4.4.4" ] ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      ipaddr: { $last: "$ipaddr" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M8mWNE-JHZT)